# I forked a project and imported it, but I cannot use it

Tags: android, android-studio, github, git-fork, jitpack

I'm very new to GitHub, so maybe it's something obvious, but I followed all the steps of many many websites (also the SO questions of course), but it doesn't work.

---

I need to change up [this](https://github.com/krokyze/uCrop-n-Edit) GitHub project. (Which is actually a fork of [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) one)

Importing the GitHub project via Gradle and using it works like a charm. So because I need some little changes, I followed these steps:

- I forked it
- I changed the code how I needed it
- I made a new release (3.1.1): [this](https://github.com/tabkus/odomacrop) is my fork

Then:

- I added `maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }` to my root gradle
- I imported my fork in the app gradle: `implementation 'com.github.tabkus:odomacrop:3.1.1'`
- I synchronized gradle
- The importing of my fork seems to work fine because it doesn't show an error and it downloads a lot of data

**But**: I cannot use the code. I cannot import the classes. In this case I need for example the class  `UCrop` as in the code

```
UCrop.of(...)
      .withMaxResultSize(1080, 1080)
      .start(activity);
```

But I cannot import it. I cannot import any class. I also tried `Invalidate caches and restart` in Android Studio but that didn't help either...

It simply says: `Cannot resolve symbol 'UCrop'`

[image: img]

**EDIT:**

I followed the answer and it solved an error. But it still didn't work. So I checked it on jitpack.io . The error now is `Execution failed for task ':ucrop:signReleasePublication'. > Could not read PGP secret key`. I looked it up on the internet but I couldn't find a fix for that. I assume some of the Gradle settings shall include some signing key and mine lack such a key. But since it is a fork, my Gradle files are exactly the same files. (I only made minor changes to some java.classes) [jitpack.io/com/github/tabkus/odomacrop/2.2.7-2/build.log](http://jitpack.io/com/github/tabkus/odomacrop/2.2.7-2/build.log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

1. Do not trust Android Studio sync, it sometimes does not popup errors for u
2. Using Gradle CLI directly to run a simple "assmeble" task like `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` for an Android project.(Add `-s` to show more stacktrace if necessary)
3. In my case above command threw an error below:

> > Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>   Could not find com.github.tabkus:odomacrop:3.1.1.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/tabkus/odomacrop/3.1.1/odomacrop-3.1.1.pom
>   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/tabkus/odomacrop/3.1.1/odomacrop-3.1.1.pom
>   - https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/tabkus/odomacrop/3.1.1/odomacrop-3.1.1.pom
>   Required by:
>   project :app

4. Now the problem is obvious: your JitPack release got some problem absolutely. So I went to https://jitpack.io/#tabkus/odomacrop to check status:

[image]

5. Click the log icon, you will see the root cause:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I now fixed these issues and created a new release. It doesn't work either. So I checked it on jitpack.io as you did. The error now is `Execution failed for task ':ucrop:signReleasePublication'. > Could not read PGP secret key`
I looked it up in the internet but I couldn't find a fix for that. I assume some of the gradle settings shall include some signing key and mine lack such a key. But since it is a fork, my gradle files are exactly the same files. (I only made minor changes to some java.classes) https://jitpack.io/com/github/tabkus/odomacrop/2.2.7-2/build.log

Comment: The original repo published to MavenCentral, it gets signing key/value from  rootProject‘s ext: https://github.com/tabkus/odomacrop/blob/master/ucrop/publish.gradle#L70 
MavenCentral requires signing configuration, while jitpack I think does not, you can remove those configurations (publish.gradle line 2, 68-74). You MUST check it locally as its doc mentioned: https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/  `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`.

What's more, I suggest you change the group name of https://github.com/tabkus/odomacrop/blob/master/ucrop/build.gradle#L5 to avoid getting someone else confused.

Comment: If any other issues happen, I suggest you close this one and create another question, because comments have characters limitation and can not post images.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you see as error message:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.6/ucrop-2.2.6.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.6/ucrop-2.2.6.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.6/ucrop-2.2.6.pom
Required by:
project :app
```

Check first if this is similar to [`Yalantis/uCrop` issue 779](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/issues/779) -with `Yalantis/uCrop` being the original project)

> you just move:
> `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` from
> `build.gradle (Project)` to
> `settings.gradle`
>
> ```sh
> dependencyResolutionManagement {
>    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
>    repositories {
>        google()
>        mavenCentral()
>        jcenter()
>        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
>        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
>    }
> }
> rootProject.name = "<Project Name>"
> include ':app'
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure which error you mean. I don't get an error. I just cannot import the class, it says `Cannot resolve symbol 'UCrop'`. I updated the question and attached a screenshot. I think I didn't explain good what the issue exactly was

Comment: However, if I try what you suggested it fails to sync gradle with this message: `Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [settings_33sy7yotaht14ypku7jp6tfyq$_run_closure1@3de9ca5] on settings 'ProjectName' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings`

Comment: @LukasNiessen OK. I would still suggest looking into those settings, but I don't know gradle enough to bring new advice.

Comment: Well these 2 DSLs of maven central declaration are equivalent, should not be the cause of error.